# Taking sheaf of union of algebraic open subsets is same as intersection of sections

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $I(V) = \{ f \in k[x_1, \dots, x_n] : f(P) = 0, \forall p \in V\}$ be the vanishing ideal of $V$, and let $k[V] = k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I(V)$ be the coordinate ring of $V$ (ring of regular functions). Let $(V, \mathcal{O}_V)$ be a sheaf of regular functions, that is for each $f \in \mathcal{O}_V(U)$ and $P \in U$ there exists a neighborhood of $P$ such that on that neighborhood $f = \cfrac{g}{h}$ for $h(P) \neq 0$ and $g,h \in k[V]$, where $V$ is irreducible and $U$ is an open (wrt Zariski topology) algebraic subset of $V$. My question, if we have an open cover $ \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n U_i = U$, is it true that $\mathcal{O}_V(U) = \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n \mathcal{O}_V(U_i)$? If we define principal open subsets $ U_i = D(h_i) = \{P \in V: h_i(P) \neq 0\}$ (any open algebraic subset can be written as a finite union of principal open subsets), then is it true for them, i.e. in this case does $\mathcal{O}_V(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nU_i) = \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n \mathcal{O}_V(U_i)$?

Comment: Could you say explicitly how you define the sections $\mathcal O_V(U)?$

Comment: Hey, yeah, I just did. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Another question - are you assuming $V$ to be irreducible (i.e. $I(V)$ prime)? I ask because to make sense of this intersection, I want all of these $\mathcal O_V(U_i)$ to be subrings of some larger ring in which the intersection occurs. If $V$ is irreducible then we can take this to be the function field $k(V)$, but if that's not the case I'm not wholly sure what these are all subrings of. You can also work without the intersection and use the equalizer sequence for sheaves to relate $\mathcal O_V(U)$ to the $\mathcal O_V(U_i)$.

Comment: Yes, $V$ is irreducible. I added that in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, for this intersection to make sense I want to explicitly state that we are dealing with subrings of $k(V)$. In case you're unfamiliar, $k(V)$ will be defined as the set of all pairs $(U, f)$ where $U \subseteq V$ is nonempty and open and $f$ is regular on $U$, i.e. $f \in \mathcal O_V(U)$. We furthermore insist that $(U, f) = (W, g)$ if $f, g$ are equal on $U \cap W$. This defines a field $k(V)$ and all of the $\mathcal O_V(U)$ naturally embed into $k(V)$ via $f \mapsto (U, f)$. You can check that this is injective by density of nomempty open subsets of $V$. See Hartshorne 1.3 for a reference.

By the way, we can effectively forget the $U$ in a pair $(U, f)$ by considering the domain $dom(f)$ to be the largest open set on which $f$ is regular. More formally, this is the union over all $W$ such that $(W, f) = (U, f)$, which yields $(dom(f), f) = (U, f)$. I'm abusing notation a bit here but I hope you'll believe that such a representive for the class of $(U, f)$ can be found.

With this aside, given $f \in k(V)$ what does it mean for $f$ to be in $\mathcal O_V(U)$? As you wrote, it means $f$ must be regular on $U$, so using the notation I had above, $U \subseteq dom(f)$. This immediately yields one inclusion. As $U_i \subseteq U$, $U \subseteq dom(f)$ implies $U_i \subseteq dom(f)$. In english, as $f$ is regular on $U$ it is regular on its subset $U_i$. Symbolically, $\mathcal O_V(U) \subseteq \mathcal O_V(U_i)$. This therefore holds for the intersection, so $\mathcal O_V(U) \subseteq \bigcap \mathcal O_V(U_i)$.

On the other hand, suppose $f \in \bigcap \mathcal O_V(U_i)$ Then $f$ is in every $\mathcal O_V(U_i)$, i.e. it is regular at every point in every $U_i$. Formally, this means $U_i \subseteq dom(f)$ for all $i$. Hence, the union $U = \bigcup U_i \subseteq dom(f)$ and we this have $f \in \mathcal O_V(U)$. Hence, $\mathcal O_V(U) \subseteq \bigcap \mathcal O_V(U_i) \subseteq \mathcal O_V(U)$ and we arrive at equality.

I'd like to explain a bit more of the equalizer sequence I mentioned in the comments, as it gives you a similar result without worrying about making sure everything is a subring of $k(V)$. Indeed, what I mean is that the following diagram is an equalizer sequence:

$$
\mathcal O_V(U) \rightarrow \prod_i \mathcal O_V(U_i) \rightrightarrows \prod_{i, j} \mathcal O_V(U_i \cap U_j)
$$

The first map takes $f \mapsto (f|_{U_1}, \dots, f|_{U_n})$. Also, we write an element of $\prod_{i, j} \mathcal O_V(U_i \cap U_j)$ as a matrix $(f_{ij})$ where $f_{ij} \in \mathcal O_V(U_i \cap U_j)$. The top map $\mathcal O_V(U_i) \rightarrow \prod_{i, j} \mathcal O_V(U_i \cap U_j)$ takes $(f_1, \dots, f_n) \mapsto (f_i|_{U_i \cap U_j})_{ij}$ and the bottom map is the transpose of this, i.e. $(f_j|_{U_i \cap U_j})_{ij}$.

If you're unfamiliar with category theory, this basically states that the map $\mathcal O_V(U) \longrightarrow \prod \mathcal O_V(U_i)$ is injective and that the image of this map is the set of tuples $(f_1, \dots, f_n)$ which map to the same thing under both maps $\prod \mathcal O_V(U_i) \rightrightarrows \prod_{i, j} \mathcal O_V(U_i \cap U_j)$, i.e. $f_i|_{U_i \cap U_j} = f_j|_{U_i \cap U_j}$ for all $i, j$. These are formulations of the identity and gluong axioms of a sheaf. So this equalizer diagram means that $\mathcal O_V(U)$ is isomorphic to the subring of $\prod \mathcal O_V(U_i)$ consisting of compatible intersections in the sense I just defined. This yields an understanding of $\mathcal O_V(U)$ in terms of all of the $\mathcal O_V(U_i)$ similar to what you were asking for.

Comment: In this case is $k(V)$ the direct limit of  $\mathcal{O}_V(U_i)$?